# Filling up nested struct in c++ with a lot o unique data

Tags: c++, struct

I've got some struct in cpp

```
    struct Vertex
    {
      GLfloat position[3];
      GLubyte color[4];
      GLfloat textCoord[2];
      GLfloat normal[3];
    }

    Vertex verts[5];
```

What I need to do now, is to put a lot of unique data into. The thing is, that it is very impeded, very messy and horrowing...

```
verts[3].position[0] = 0.5; verts[3].position[1] = -0.5; verts[3].position[2] = 0.0;
verts[3].color[0] = 255; verts[3].color[1] = 255; verts[3].color[2] = 0; verts[3].color[3] = 255;
verts[3].normal[0] = verts[3].normal[1] = verts[3].normal[2] = 0.0;
verts[3].textCoord[0] = 0.0; verts[3].textCoord[1] = 0.0;
```

How can I put it in easier way? Of course I could read it from file, but for some reason I don't want to.
To me the greatest way would be to fill it as an array or something. I thought about overloading some operator, but I can't find any solution in this idea because most of them are one argument only.

Answer (score 0):

Write a simple program to generate test data to a file.

Modify your program to input the test data from the file.

The file will serve two purposes: 1) You get the same data during each test run for debugging; and 2) You can change the data easily without having to rebuild the program.

Answer (score 0):

Something like below should work for you - it's just array initialization:

```
struct Vertex
{
  GLfloat position[3];
  GLubyte color[4];
  GLfloat textCoord[2];
  GLfloat normal[3];
};

Vertex verts[5] =
{
  {{0.5, -0.5, 0.0}, {255, 255, 0, 255}, {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0, 0.0}},
  < ... repeat for other vertices probably with other numbers ... >
};
```

Comment: Can't do that... `invalid initializer for array member`

Comment: There are no "code" member in this structure. This message probably has been generated by some other code.

Comment: Oh, I see... Please add in the beginning: #include <GL/glu.h> and semicolon after "Vertex" definition

Comment: What OS? What compiler by the way?

Comment: Ubuntu 11.04, gcc-4.6.1